# How To Use a UITextField with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, objectmapper

I recently started using Alamofire over URLSession just to be comfortable in it and switching to a more readable a easy code base. I am creating an app where I have a UITextField and whenever the user writes something and hits return, it searches through the API for the specific data. I would like to start out by printing that data into the console for the moment, but I can't figure out how to do that. How can I achieve that to search any specific data from my Model?

EDIT:
The base URL looks like this: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=[API_KEY]".
To search for a specific title we add "&query=[name of the movie]". How can I add that last part for the query to what the user inputs in the textfield?

PS:I used ObjectMapper for my Model.

Comment: You mean you want to print Alamofire API call response to the console?

Comment: I want to use the Alamofire to fetch the data from the api and print it into the console not just the text that's inside the textfield. For example, in my model I created different parameters to represent information about a movie. I have title, Description, release date etc. I want to search for the title and print back the description for example.

Answer (score 0):

If we get default API call response as json like this

```
"success" : true,
"message" : "successfull"
"data" : {
       "field1" : "some data"
       }
}
```

So we can handle this response like this

```
AF.request(URL(string: "myurl.com")!,
               method: .get, 
               headers: AppConstants.headers)
        .validate(statusCode:200..<300)
        .validate(contentType:[AppConstants.contentTypeJson])
        .responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let data):
                guard let json = data as? [String:AnyObject] else {
                    return
                }

                let isSuccess =  (json["success"])?.boolValue ?? false
                if isSuccess {
                    print(json) //You can do something with response
                }else{
                    Data.currentError = (json["message"]) as? String ?? "-"
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
```

more info: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-handling